# linkedin api strange empty response

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm using the linkedin Javascript API to retrive the posts of a group but I have empty response.
As you can see If I request a group detail the API response have something inside but, if I ask the posts the response is empty.

This is my code

```
$.getScript("http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=true", function success() {
    IN.init({
        'api_key': apiKey,
        onLoad: "onLoadedLinkedin"
    });
});


onLoadedLinkedin = function(){
    console.log('linkedin init: ok');

    IN.API.Raw("groups/35920").result(function callback(result) { console.log(result);});
    IN.API.Raw("groups/35920/posts?count=5&start=5").result(function callback(result) { console.log(result);});
}
```

And there are the response

[image]

How can I retrive correctly this posts?

Comment: I can't see in your code the authentication code: does your webpage allow user auth?

Comment: Do I need to authenticate mysefl to read the post but not to read the group info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some groups in LinkedIn can be marked "members-only", which would require you to authenticate as a particular member that has access to the group you are trying to read before being able to see the contents of the group.

Comment: You are rigth! Thank you ^^